# PHP: after user selects appropriate radio button, how do I insert the data for that radio button into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

how do I insert the data for a radio button a user selects?

Comment: my html form prompts the user for a course number and time.

Comment: You can build something from this quick online course: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp : Otherwise, post your code. If it is a syntax error and you need a fresh pair of eyes, we need to see what you have developed so far.

Comment: @Malovich — (a) That's a dreadful course that should be avoided and (b) It doesn't cover the topic of this question

Comment: users are prompted two things: course number and time.  from this, we are making a table that shows data found for a course at that time from our db.

Comment: You're looking at two seperate pages: one to determine the section, the other to take in the input, if you're doing this through HTML/PHP. You *can* get it all on the same form...if you're willing to use javascript (or any library based on js) to .hide the form and .show it on the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear to me, do you wanna know how to save a radio button input to a database or how to setup something where a user clicks a radiobutton and based on the selection he must fill out a form?

Assuming your HTML for your radio button is like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"> Choice 1
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"> Choice 2
```

You can save that to your database by:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (choice) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['choice'])."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you submit different fields based on the radiobutton that is selected you can just use:

```
if ($_POST['choice'] == 1) {
 // Do something with the input fields connected to choice1
} else {
// Do something with the input fields connected to choice2 (Assuming you only use 2 radio selects)
}
```

EDIT //

Based on your HTML FORM you can use the code below to insert the values into your database:

```
if (isset ($_POST['Submit'])) {

    if (empty ($_POST['CID'])) {

        echo 'You must fill out your Course ID, <a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Go back</a>.';

    } elseif (empty ($_POST['Time'])) {

        echo 'You must fill out the Time field, <a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Go back</a>.';

    } else {

        // Insert into mysql database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (CID, Time) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CID'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Time'])."')") or die (mysql_error());

        echo 'Thank you, your request has been submitted.';
    }

} else {

    echo 'Error : No Submit action has been placed.';

}

?>
```

Comment: @Nyson, how are you gonna do a SQL injection based on a value of a radio button?

Comment: @Adriaan: The HTML page would be the _last_ place I'd go to if I wanted to hack Chea Indians site. $_POST take POST variables, which may be sent without viewing the page at all, [here's an example with telnet](http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/web/cours/ch01.html).

Comment: @Nyson, thanks for the link, interesting. I've also did it quick but as you can see in the other code i did use mysql_real_escape_string.

(at)Chea Indian, your php code makes me confusing since your question is kinda difference..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to study up a bit.

- [XHTML/HTML Forms and Input](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/tutorials/accessible-forms/beginner/)
- [Accessing External input in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)
- [Avoiding SQL injections in PHP](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

After reading up a bit, you could piece these bits together and ask a more precise question.

For accessing different pages, I suggest you either look in to manipulating DOM via JavaScript (preferably assisted by tools such as jQuery) or making multiple pages in PHP.

Your project is *not in any means at all scalable*, which makes it increasingly harder to maintain your project for each line of code you write. Please look into [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) and [object oriented programming](http://se.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).